# Convert NETCDF file to TIFF when coordinates are variables (not coordinates)

Tags: python, tiff, netcdf, gdal, netcat

How to convert the NetCDF to TIFF, when the coordinates are stored in another NetCDF file (and are a irregular grid, since this covers the Arctic region)?

An example of the NetCDF file can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1i4OGCQhKlZ056H1YHq4hTb0EbEkl-pYd

The NetCDF file with the coordinates can be donwnloaded here: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1WVzZ--NnHSPkJmBqlGwXAN7abXM5_uNh

(Just additional information files only provide the following in what regards coordinates):

```
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_bounds_crs=EPSG:4326
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_max=90
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lat_min=57.8
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_max=180
  NC_GLOBAL#geospatial_lon_min=-180
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

[image]

I know how to a do a conversion with Gdaltranslate, but the problem is if I apply it, my generated netCDF file will not be georeferenced, as lat/lon are not as coordinates, but stored as variables on another netCDF file. So below I have my so far progress trying to do this
with a GDAL-Python. It results on the a rotated image, still seems not georeferenced.
Also:  it seems I managed to insert the coordinates but their name do not change to y and x, and keep as c and r, despite having changed them (see pics below).

- - - EDIT - -
      This is what I tried so far, and the output is a tiff (wrongly rotated) and no coordinates on the axis:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import rioxarray as rio 
    
xds = xr.open_dataset(r'path_to_netdfc')
xdc = xr.open_dataset(r"path_to_netcdf_with_coordinates")
    
# Adds coordinates to x and y
xds.coords["c"] = xdc.mp_lon[1,:]
xds.coords["r"] = xdc.mp_lat[:,1]
xds
    
# Reorganize the netCDF file into standard names/locations
xds = xds.squeeze().rename_dims({"c": "x", "r": "y"}).transpose('y', 'x')
    
xds.rio.write_crs('epsg:4326', inplace=True)
    
    
#Take the variable that I'm interested in
df = xds['daily_fraction']
    
#It was giving me error later on, so i needed to set_spatial_dims
df = df.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim='x', y_dim='y')
    
#Save the GeoTIFF file:
df.rio.to_raster(r"C:\PHD\name_of_output.tiff")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't you just open the the variable netCDF with xarray, add the coordinates from another netCDF and then save the updated xarray dataset as raster (`dfout.to_raster(file.tif)`)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. So, I extracted the variables and save them as coordinates as you suggested:

``xds  // this is my NectDFC to be converted to a tiff
xdc  // this is the NetCDF with the coordinates as variables
xds.rename_dims({"c": "x", "r": "y"}) // I renamed the dimensions 
lon = xdc.mp_lon
lat = xdc.mp_lat
xds.coords["x"] = lon
xds.coords["y"] = lat``


how could I save it now as a tif? with ``xds.to_raster(file.tif)`` i get the error  'Dataset' object has no attribute 'to_raster'

Comment: Sorry, it is not so trivial indeed... The dataset has to be raster xarray dataset beforehand, so I wonder if `xds.rio.to_raster` works?

Comment: I did in the end ('xds.rio.to_raster'), yes, it saved a tiff but rotated.. :( and in the axis I still don't get lat/lon but the number dimensions.  I will write the whole script /edit my question so you can see the result.

Comment: If you don't `.transpose('y', 'x')`, does the rotation correct itself?

Comment: I think x should be "c" and y should be "r" as in y = rows and x = columns

Comment: @PaulH if I don't transpose, I get this error: InvalidDimensionOrder: Invalid dimension order. Expected order: ('y', 'x')You can use `DataArray.transpose('y', 'x')` to reorder your dimensions. Data variable: daily_fraction

Comment: @KelMarkert I tried to do both things:
1) `xds = xds.squeeze().rename_dims({"r": "x","c": "y", }).transpose('y', 'x')`
2) `xds = xds.squeeze().rename_dims({"c": "y", "r": "x"}).transpose('y', 'x')`

Both options outputs an image, but at this point I'm not sure if my mistake is how I visualize it. This is a polar dataset, and I don't know what would be the best way to visualize it to understand if the output figures make any sense et al..

Answer (score 0):

Your files do not follow any standard that I know of. Each dimension is in its separate dataset.

If you are sure that the longitude/latitude is linear - which it might not be given that your dataset covers the polar regions - you can simply use `gdal_translate` to convert to TIFF and then `gdal_edit.py -a_ulurll ulx uly urx ury llx lly` to set a geotransform with your coordinates. But this will work only if the longitude/latitude are linear relative to your pixels.

Comment: Yes, this is my struggle... the coordinates are not a normal grid - and are stored on the second link that I shared (i.e. https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1WVzZ--NnHSPkJmBqlGwXAN7abXM5_uNh) .. this is why I'm adding coordinates (or trying to) from that dataset to the one I want to convert with the lines ```xds.coords["c"] = xdc.mp_lon[1,:]
xds.coords["r"] = xdc.mp_lat[:,1]```

Comment: You can't do this without warping unless there is a projection that can transform linear coordinates to your coordinates.